# Error display when i load my page in online (Error in "web.config")

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I am fresher in ASP.Net C# (4.0)...
I developed one website and upload in server. It works in my local system. But when i upload in server page display one error in web.config. 
AND ERROR IS.....

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in "web.config" file when i load page in online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298882/error-in-web-config-file-when-i-load-page-in-online)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs if there is framework issue. Make sure the local framework and framework on remote system is same. OR Right click virtual directory and Select the latest .Net framework.

Comment: my web.config code is...

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
    <!--Local Connection string-->
  <add name="Conn" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\meena.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: First try to add the configuration mentioned in error message to web config file. It it doesn't work then check framework of application pool where your virtual directory is placed

Comment: How to add the configuration mentioned in error message to web config file?