# Error Umbraco Membership Provider

Tags: umbraco

I just uploaded my Umbraco website to my server, but I'm getting the following error when trying to access it:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source Error: 


Line 143:      <providers>
Line 144:        <clear />
Line 145:        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
Line 146:        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
Line 147:      </providers>
```

And there's no other information about the error. Anybody knows how to deal with this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, noted. Already edited my post. But all the information I got from the error it's in there, I have no other information from the error page. Do you have any idea about what this error could be? Thank you very much

Comment: Just solved the issue. For anyone that founds this kind of issue, you have to fix the permissions for files and folders in your server.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because I accidentally removed global.asax and packages.config from my Visual Studio solution. I restored these files from recycle bin and everything was fine again (think it was missing global.asax that was the culprit).

Answer (score 1):

Just check the domain service settings, I am not clear about all the settings step but first of all you must set the target to 4.0(or on current) from the settings.

Reference - [Error in "web.config" file when i load page in online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298882/error-in-web-config-file-when-i-load-page-in-online)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)